# Why is $ \mathrm{SO}(q_4) $ smooth over $ \mathbb Q $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Based on [http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf), page 303.

Let $ q_4 = X_1 X_2 + X_3 X_4 $.

I tried calculating smoothness of $ \mathrm{SO}(q_4) $ over $ \mathbb Q $, in the identity element/matrix, but something is going wrong somewhere and I can't figure out what. We have
$$ \mathrm{SO}(q_4) \cong \mathbb Q[X_{11}, \dots, X_{44}] / (f_{11}, \dots, f_{14}, f_{22}, \dots, f_{24}, f_{33}, f_{34}, f_{44}, \vert X_{ij} \vert_{ij} - 1) $$
For some polynomials $ f_{ij} $, given for $ i \not = j $ by
$$ f_{ij} = X_{1i} X_{2j} + X_{2i} X_{1j} + X_{3i} X_{4j} + X_{4i} X_{3j} - c_{ij} $$
for some $ c_{ij} \in \mathbb Z $.

Note that

- $ \frac{\partial f_{12}}{\partial X_{ij}} = 1 $ iff $ i = j \in \{ 1, 2 \} $ and $ 0 $ otherwise.
- $ \frac{\partial f_{34}}{\partial X_{ij}} = 1 $ iff $ i = j \in \{ 3, 4 \} $ and $ 0 $ otherwise.
- $ \frac{\partial \vert X_{ij} \vert_{ij} - 1}{X_{ij}} = 1 $ iff $ i = j $ and $ 0 $ otherwise.

This means that the matrix of partial derivatives does not have full rank (since the last row is the sum of the rows of $ f_{12} $ and $ f_{34} $), and $ \mathrm{SO}(q_4) $ is not smooth over $ \mathbb Q $, right? However, I know/suspect that $ \mathrm{SO}(q_4) $ is supposed to be smooth over $ \mathbb Q $, so where is the mistake?

Comment: It didn't have full rank because you chose the wrong vector space target to look at.  Analogous to standard $O(n)$ in differential geometry: the differential of $A^TA-I$ gives $H\mapsto A^TH+H^TA$ which only maps to symmetric matrices not the full space of matrices.

Comment: @user10354138 The wrong vector space target?